# How to put uint8list as argument for iOS method channel in Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to convert jp2 image with iOS platform channel to jpeg using UIImage class. Unfortunately I can't do it because of this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'FlutterStandardTypedData' (0x1fac3c3d8) to 'NSArray' (0x1fac372b0).
```

Here is my code in Xcode:

```html
...}else if(call.method == "convertJp2"){
                self.convertJp2(call.arguments as! [UInt8], result: result)
                }....

func convertJp2(_ imageBytes: [UInt8], result: FlutterResult){
        let image = UIImage(data:Data(imageBytes))
        if let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let filename = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("copy.jpeg")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
            result(filename)
            }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I know about this [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab#codec) but I didn't find some example of usage FlutterStandartTypedData...

Comment: Do not use the “Snippet” feature for Swift code, it works only with JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here: https://blog.csdn.net/baoolong/article/details/88901633

Issue was in cast of argument.

Now it looks like that:

```html
...}else if(call.method == "convertJp2"){
                self.convertJp2(call.arguments as! FlutterStandardTypedData, result: result)
                }....

func convertJp2(_ imageBytes: FlutterStandardTypedData, result: FlutterResult){
        let image = UIImage(data:Data(imageBytes.data))
        if let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let filename = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("copy.jpeg")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
            result(filename.path)
            }
    }
```